# Model is not on top of marker ARjs

Tags: augmented-reality, ar.js

I'm just starting out in ARjs myself. I found an issue that I'm confused on how to solve. My gltf model won't show unless it's on scale 5x and it only showed partially as in the left top corner on the actual model. My assumption is from the position, but I'm not sure how to approach this?
I already saw the https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/299 thread solution, but it didn't work.

Comment: You should show the relevant (minimal) parts of your code — an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your code so it's really hard to know what is the problem there. From what you are describing I would try scaling your object down and not up. If you only see small parts of it on a 5x scale, I guess you were inside the object this entire time. Try scaling it down to ~0.1 and see if it works. Also, make sure your model is positioned to 0,0,0 (or just don't specify the position at all ass this is the default). Another thing I think you should try is our platform [echoAR](https://www.echoar.xyz/). You can upload your models and easily have an ARjs experience. Just follow the [docs](https://docs.echoar.xyz/ar.js/deploy-experience).